# How to get the number of likes of a facebook link post using POST_ID/OBJECT_ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have an app that process input to jpeg and then post the link of the generated image to the user's timeline. now i want to get the number of likes of each post and echo it in a  with another like button(linked with the same post). how can i do that? i used 'PHP SDK' when i post the image link(in another .php file). as much as possible i want to use the `POST_ID` or `OJBECT_ID` to access the facebook post. please give some some suggestions on what to use and how can i start. this is my first time to work with facebook apps.

all i have for now is this on the processor.php. i want the out put to be on the gallery.php.
thanks in advance for any help.

processor.php

```
        if($user_id) {
          try {
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                        array(
                                          'link' => $post_link,
                                          'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                     ));
            echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
            echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                           'scope' => 'publish_stream, read_stream'
                           )); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream, read_stream' ) );
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        }
```

`

Comment: _“now i want to get the number of likes of each post and echo it in a with another like button”_ – what do you mean by “another like button”? Do you just want a standard FB like button?

Comment: thanks @CBroe..yes, if that's the easiest to have...would that also count the number of likes in the timeline post? i read a post which says that it needs JS SDK. but i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You get FB likes with

```
$likes    = $facebook->api("/".$POSTID."/likes");
```

This returns an array...

Comment: thanks @Petra.. can i merge that with my mysql query? or somthing like put it inside the query? i need to include PHP SDK for that right? thanks again

Comment: how can i get the $POSTID? i want it to be in the gallery.php. but i made the posting in the process.php. thanks

Comment: if i try to print `$likes` all it prints is the word "Array". How can i get the exact number of likes of the value of that Array? thanks for further help

Comment: You can use var_dump($likes) to view it - or make a foreach loop. And I thought you have the postid already...?